# Javascript that displays table OR definition list. How do I control which one?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I've got some javascript provided by a scheduling site that shows a week of the schedule as a table on a laptop, but as a definition list on my iPhone 4, and then in a mobile emulator, as a table on an iPhone 5. It looks terrible as a table on mobile devices, and so I need to know how to control whether it shows up as a table or definition list.

Here's the script:

```
<div id="fs-embed-Khi8C7TGs4"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        (window.$fs || (window.$fs = [])).push(["embed", {
            "root": "fs-embed-Khi8C7TGs4",
            "host": "intuatouchmassage.fullslate.com",
            "service": 1,
            "employee": 189
        }]);
        if (!window.$fs._isFullSlate) {
            var fsscr = document.createElement("script");
            fsscr.type = "text/javascript";
            fsscr.async = true;
            fsscr.src = ["http", (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "s" : ""), "://intuatouchmassage.fullslate.com/api.js"].join("");
            var other = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            other.parentNode.insertBefore(fsscr, other);
        }
    })();
</script>
<noscript>
    <p>
        <a title="Online scheduling" href="http://intuatouchmassage.fullslate.com/go/1/Massage-Therapy-60min?view=bare">Schedule appointment</a>
    </p>
</noscript>
```

The outputs on both my computer and my phone are massive and ugly, and I couldn't even get it to display correctly on this site.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Also, this sometimes displays on phones, and sometimes comes up blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Format your code, please.

Comment: Your JavaScript is broken.